# Change the color of default delete button in UITableViewCell ios 7.1.2

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7.1

I have developed an app. And changed default red color of delete button. It was working clearly. But after i upgrade my iPad iOS 7.1.2 it didn't work more.
Hereby is the code that i have used

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        for(UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews){
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"] ||) {
                ((UIView*)[subview2.subviews firstObject]).backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a NSLog to verify if there is a subview with name "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView" in your subview.subviews.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the *UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton* at the wrong time.

It seems that Apple changed the implementation so that the button is actually constructed and added to the view hierarchy after triggering  *willTransitionToState:*, and before triggering *didTransitionToState:*

Accessing the button in *didTransitionToState:* would be too late. It will have its original color while dragging it, and change the color only when you've finished swiping.

A work around is to queue the method on the thread’s run loop and not to perform it immediately, allowing the OS to add the Delete button view in the meantime.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(setupDeleteButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)setupDeleteButton
{
    [self recurseToDeleteButtonInViews:[self subviews]];
}

- (void)recurseToDeleteButtonInViews:(NSArray *)subviews
{
    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton"]){
            // You just found your button!
            // Do what ever you want with it!
            return;
        }
        if ([[subview subviews] count] > 0){
            [self recurseToDeleteButtonInViews:[subview subviews]];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**P.S.** This code is not backward compatible with iOS 6.0, since the name of the button view was changed in iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

this method will work in custom cell.

```
-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state    
{

     [super willTransitionToState:state];
     if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) ==UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) 
     {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) 
     {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class])isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
                UIImageView *delbtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];
                [delbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"]];
                [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:deleteBtn];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this workaround does what I wanted.

add this line to your cell's custom init.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        [self.contentView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
}
```

then you need to handle the observer.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"])
    {
        [self fixDeleteButtonColor];
    }
}
```

And now, I'm basically doing the same thing (like the other responses)

```
- (void)fixDeleteButtonColor
{
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
       //is not going to be in our contentView, and we may have many views there..
        if (view == self.contentView)
        {
            continue;
        }
        [self checkSubViews:view];
    }
}

- (void)checkSubViews:(UIView *)view
{
    // may be better to just compare the strings...
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"])
    {
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        UIView *subView = view.subviews[0];
        subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    else if (view.subviews.count)
    {
        for (UIView *subView in view.subviews)
        {
            [self checkSubViews:subView];
        }
    }
}
```

and, don't forget to remove the observer on dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.contentView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}
```